# Security downsides of using EquatableUserInterface

Tags: php, symfony

To prevent an automatic logout as soon as the user roles of a user change, I would like to use EquatableUserInterface and integrate my own isEqualTo() method (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#comparing-users-manually-with-equatableinterface). This method is basically the same as that from the Symfony Core, except that I remove the part with the roles:

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user): bool
{
    if (!$user instanceof self) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getPassword() !== $user->getPassword()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getSalt() !== $user->getSalt()) {
        return false;
    }

    /* Remove this part
    $currentRoles = array_map('strval', (array) $this->getRoles());
    $newRoles = array_map('strval', (array) $user->getRoles());
    $rolesChanged = \count($currentRoles) !== \count($newRoles) || \count($currentRoles) !== \count(array_intersect($currentRoles, $newRoles));
    if ($rolesChanged) {
        return false;
    }*/

    if ($this->getUsername() !== $user->getUsername()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->isAccountNonExpired() !== $user->isAccountNonExpired()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->isAccountNonLocked() !== $user->isAccountNonLocked()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->isCredentialsNonExpired() !== $user->isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->isEnabled() !== $user->isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Are there any concerns for security reasons? Assuming I would only compare the IDs with each other, would that be much more insecure than comparing several properties? Or are there better ways to allow a role change of a logged in user without logout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue some minutes ago and implemented my isEqualTo Method like:

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user): bool
{
    return $this->username === $user->getUsername() && $this->password === $user->getPassword();
}
```

It depends what properties you are using. In my case it was enough to check these properties. Imo the safest way is your snippet without the role check. The id is not part of the `UserInterface`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a security downside to this because there are less checks?

Comment: I dont think so. The method by default just checks all properties because all properties are implemented. If you can ensure that your application is save and nothing can be changed by the user it should be save to compare fewer properties. If you have an administrator who can disable accounts i would also the isEnabled check. Thats why i said it depends on your application.